# Catch all HTTP verbs on certain route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, http, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.1

How to code Laravel 5.1 router/controller to respond to any/all HTTP verbs (GET, POST, DELETE etc.) on certain route?

I can declare:

```
Route::controller('foo', 'FooController');

class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex()
    {
    }

    public function postIndex()
    {
    }
}
```

But instead of listing separate methods for all verbs possible I want something like:

```
class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function allIndex()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: there's a laravel documentation. here [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing)

Comment: I would recommend against using `Route::controller(..)` method, as it's no longer supported in later versions of Laravel. You can try `anyIndex()`, if it doesn't work you'll need to do routes the way Adnan Mumtaz suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Route::any('foo', 'FooController@allIndex');
```

You can use `any` it will work for all type of requests on a single function.

```
class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function allIndex()
    {
    }
}
```

Secondly in your controller you can check which method type of method is called using `method()`

```
public function allIndex()
{
     request()->method() // returns GET,POST, PUT, PATCH

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you are looking for:

`Route::any('foo', [
        'uses' => 'FooController@allIndex'
    ]);`